# installing rails with gem , error loading command : install undefined method 'invoke_with_build_args`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, debian-based

I'm try to install rails on Debian. when run this command

`gem install rails`

I gave this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method ``invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

even when I try this command:
`gem install`
I gave this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method ``invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I used this link to build ruby from sources [ruby 2.1.2 build instruction](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10)

what can I do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For who compile from source, they must checked dependencies. I think you need to install this library :

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then you must recompiled ruby and everything worked.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution for MacOS environment ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `zlib` development headers.

Refer to your OS's package manager instructions on how to do this.

On a `RedHat` derivative it would look something like this:

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

For ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this isn't help. my zlib1g-dev already installed and it's version is: _i   1:1.2.7.dfsg-13_. is this version out of date ?

Comment: which method from your install link did you follow? `rbenv`, `rvm`, or `source`?

Comment: I build ruby from source

Comment: please supply the full output of `dpkg -l | grep zlib`. Not sure why `ruby` isn't finding the headers.

Comment: here is the output : ii  zlib1g:amd64                          1:1.2.7.dfsg-13                    amd64        compression library - runtime
ii  zlib1g-dev:amd64                      1:1.2.7.dfsg-13                    amd64        compression library - development

Comment: the package in question is openssl-devel for CentOS.

Comment: Installed `ruby-2.1.9` from source on `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

`dpkg -l | grep zlib`

`ii  zlib1g:amd64 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1  amd64 compression library - runtime`

`ii  zlib1g-dev:amd64 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64  compression library - development`